# RecaptchaV3 returns 0.9 score for Selenium

Tags: selenium, web, recaptcha, captcha, recaptcha-v3

I use recaptcha v3 on my site.
Captcha cannot detect a robot (Selenium) - result always success.
I expected that score will be 0.1, but it always equals 0.9 for human and for Selenium.
Now my site is under construction and I use "localhost" domain.
Why captcha cannot detect a robot?

Comment: What's the question here? How to block selenium?

Comment: Yes. I expect that Selenium will be detected as robot and score will be low.

Comment: That's not a question either.

Comment: OK. Why captcha cannot detect a robot?

Comment: Same situation for me. Did you find a solution? 

I have reCAPTCHA v3 implemented in a form. I have filled in the form about 50 times. Half in an automated way with Selenium and the other half by filling in the form manually. In all cases, the score was 0.9

Comment: @didaquis did you find a solution for this or did it get better after some days on its own?

Comment: @VladL The truth is that I could not solve it. In my case, I decided to just do a workaround and modify the allowed threshold based on whether the environment was production or development.

Comment: @didaquis in my case it started delievering other than 0.9 results after around 1k+ assesments. Also it started inclduing LOW_CONFIDENCE_REASON right after google enabled enhanced scores for me on my request... I'm talking about regular usage right now, not about testing

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you are unlikely to be able to do this, otherwise what is the point of it? If it was your product (site) then it would be fashionable to add your IP to the white list and block it by adding it to the URL? Captcha_no = true well or something like that. And if the site is not yours, as you indicated above, then the only solution is to simply add wait and enter what you need with pens. for example

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait;
WebElement yourName = wait.until (ExpectedCondition.visibilityOfElemetLocated (your element after captcha));
```

I know that this is not what you expected, but unfortunately I think that there is no other solution.

P.S. Can we have a look at your code? To better understand what the problem is

Comment: Problem in next: captcha can be passed by Selenium:) I use code from docs: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3